# Returning images from a specific album with CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, model

Consider I have two database tables: `images` and `albums`. They have these schemas:

```
images:
id, orig_name, hash, filename, uploaded, views, album_id, user_id, server_id

albums:
id, hash, name, description, user_id
```

The `album_id` field in the `images` table points to the `id` field in the `albums` table. Pretty simple one-to-many stuff. An image can belong to one album and an album can have many images. What I'm confused about is how to get images from a specified album in my CakePHP `Image` model. At the moment this is my model:

```
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Image';
    public $belongsTo = array('Server', 'Album');

    public function getImages($options) {
        $params = array('conditions' => array());

        // Specific user
        if (!empty($options['userID'])) {
            array_push($params['conditions'], array('Image.user_id' => $options['userID']));
        }

        // Specific album
        if (!empty($options['albumHash'])) {
            array_push($params['conditions'], array('Image.album_id' => $options['albumHash']));
        }

        // Order of images
        $params['order'] = 'Image.uploaded DESC';
        if (!empty($options['order'])) {
            $params['order'] = $options['order'];
        }

        return $this->find('all', $params);
    }
}
```

What I want it to do is return images from a specific album based on the album hash (the `hash` field in the table). I know how I can make this work if I had the album ID, but I don't, I only have the hash.

I already have an album model that's just this:

```
class Album extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Album';
}
```

but I'm not even sure if that's relevant. :p

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($options['albumHash'])) {
    array_push($params['conditions'], array('Album.hash' => $options['albumHash']));
}
```

Comment: It's so simple... why didn't this occur to me. God I love Cake. Thanks. :D

Comment: No problem and yes, it's pretty simple ;)